# Mvc Routing - Multiple Match Url

Tags: .net, url, model-view-controller, routes, attributes

I have a problem about Seo Routing. It is briefly as follow;
some pages have fixed Urls, not change with any ids or parameter.
One of them is;

```
    [Route("adres-secimi")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Step2()
    {
        List<DashboardAddressModel> modelList = _authentication.GetUserData().AddressList.Select(x => new DashboardAddressModel
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Tittle = x.Title,
            FullName = x.RecipientFullName,
            Phone = x.RecipientPhoneNummer,
            Detail = x.Details,
            IsDefault = x.IsDefault,
            CityName = x.District.City.Name,
            DistrictName = x.District.Name,
            Identity = x.RecipientIdentityNumber
        }).ToList();

        return View(modelList.OrderBy(x => !x.IsDefault).ToList());
    }
```

And some pages have dinamic urls. Two of them are following;

1)

```
    [Route("{child}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string child)
    {
        Category childCategory = _categoryService.GetByUrl(child);
        if (childCategory != null)
        {
            if (childCategory.ProductList.Count > 0)
            {


                return RedirectToAction("SingleProduct", new { child = childCategory });

            }
            else if (childCategory.ChildCategoryList.Count > 0)
            {
                CategoryIndexModel model = new CategoryIndexModel
                {
                    ChildId = childCategory.Id,
                    ChildUrl = childCategory.Url,
                    ChildName = childCategory.TitleName,
                    MetaDescription = childCategory.MetaDescription,
                    MetaKeywords = childCategory.MetaKeywords
                };

                return View(model);
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

2)

```
    [Route("{parent}/{child}/{productId:int}")]
    public ActionResult SingleProduct(string parent,string child, int productId)
    {            
        Category childCategory = _categoryService.GetByUrl(child);
        Category parentCategory = _categoryService.GetByUrl(parent);
        Product product = _productService.GetById(productId);

        SingleProductCategoryModel model = new SingleProductCategoryModel
        {
            ChildId = childCategory.Id,
            ChildName = childCategory.TitleName,
            ChildLink = childCategory.Link,
            ParentName = parentCategory.TitleName,
            ParentId = (int?)parentCategory.Id,
            ParentLink = parentCategory.Link,
            Rating = childCategory.Rating,
            IsInWishList = (_authentication.GetUserData() != null) ? _authentication.GetUserData().WishList.Any(w => w.IsActive && w.CategoryId == childCategory.Id) : false,
            ProductId = product.Id,
            MetaDescription = childCategory.MetaDescription,
            MetaKeywords = childCategory.MetaKeywords,
            InformationText = childCategory.InformationText,
            DescriptionList = childCategory.DescriptionList.Select(x => new SingleProductDescriptionModel
            {
                Type = x.Type,
                Name = Utility.Converter.GetDescriptionName(x.Type),
                Content = x.Content
            }).ToList(),
            BigImageList = childCategory.ImageList.Where(x => x.Type == ImageTypes.slider_big_img).Select(x => new SingleProductImageModel
            {
                Type = x.Type,
                Path = x.Path,
                Description = x.Description,
                DisplayOrder = x.DisplayOrder - 1
            }).ToList(),
            SmallImageList = childCategory.ImageList.Where(x => x.Type == ImageTypes.slider_small_img).Select(x => new SingleProductImageModel
            {
                Type = x.Type,
                Path = x.Path,
                Description = x.Description,
                DisplayOrder = x.DisplayOrder - 1
            }).ToList(),
            CommentCount = childCategory.CommentList.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

When i try going to the dynamic urls they are routing the right actions but after defined the routes for dynamic urls, the fixed routes started giving error "multiple url match". 
I would be really glad if someone can help me for the solution.
and also showing the product id on url is not the best solution maybe you have any better idea?

Comment: Mvc  router first fetchs controller name then action name

Comment: What language is this in? Replace the [seo] tag with that, or you might not get any help